# mod_rewrite with ? in the original URL like YouTube

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok I want to simulate the YouTube URL and redirect it to my real URL. Reason being is I used a random string to make video ID's so they aren't guessable by sequence. 
I have the links as so

```
http://www.mysite.com/watch?v=Dxdotx3iT1
```

and want to redirect to

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=videos&section=view&v=Dxdotx3iT1
```

Can't seem to figure out the mod rewrite. Also using a ? I believe tells it to do something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust your RewriteRule to include the query string using the [QSA] (query string attached) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^watch$ index.php?page=video&section=view [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. That is awesome. Works great. I've been pulling my hair out. LOL I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.+)
RewriteRule ^watch /index\.php?page=videos&section=view&v=%1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Since ceejayoz answered first and it does work. I will accept that one. Thanks for the answer as well.

Comment: also, with QSA set you don't need to explicitly pass the v parameter from the original query...

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me, so in the end I found through trial and error the following worked for me;

The RewriteRule to get my URL to look like this https://www.example.com/video/watch?v=UnIq3Id follows;

```
RewriteRule ^video\/watch\?*$ index.php?page=video [L,QSA]
```

I found that the following rule I had previously set up to make my URL look like this https://www.example.com/video/UnIq3Id interfered with my redirecting;

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&v=$2
```

Simply commenting it out fixed the issue, as follows;

```
#RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&v=$2
```

The RewriteRule to get my URL to look like this https://www.example.com/watch?v=UnIq3Id is as follows;

```
RewriteRule ^watch\?*$ index.php?page=video [L,QSA]
```

I found that the following rule I had previously set up to make my URL look like this https://www.example.com/video/ interfered with my redirecting;

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Simply commenting it out fixed the issue, as follows;

```
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Hope it helped someone and saved you the headache I had, people are not so forthcoming on this issue at times [How do you write an htaccess RewriteRule to make my urls work like youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997156/how-do-you-write-an-htaccess-rewriterule-to-make-my-urls-work-like-youtube).

Comment: That is not really a solution if someone also needs the other rule. What you should have done is just create a rewrite condition on the first rule to ignore URL with `/watch' then both rules will work together.

Comment: Can you provide an example